# How to make a 2d array of mutex locks?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, mutex

Im still slightly new to programming so sorry if I'm not making too much sense. im trying to make a 2d array of mutex locks to correspond with another 2d array of objects I am working with. Here is my code

```
#define NUM_THREADS 100

static pthread_mutex_t mutexes[NUM_THREADS][NUM_THREADS] = { 
  for(int i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS ; i++) {
    P99_DUPL(NUM_THREADS, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER);
  }
};
```

Am i doing this correctly? is it even possible to do this thing?

edit: I get the error "expected expression before ‘for’" when I try to compile.

Comment: Is it possible to have n×m mutex for things in an array? yes, but probably not sensible. Can it be initialized that way? Not in C/C++ (unless some new version introduces some kind of list comprehension). Also unless your target machine has on the order of 100 cores/threads it does not make sense to run this many threads. A good heuristic for a thread pool size is n + ln(n) where n is the number of available CPU cores/threads.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try to backpedal and come up with a different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define and initialize a 2D array using a `for` loop. Since you deal with a pretty large array (100 x 100), the best way is probably to separate the definition and the initialization.

For a 2D interger array that would be:

```
int i, j;
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100
int my_array[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];  // Define the variable

for (i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)           // Initialize the variable
{
    for (j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE; ++j)
    {
        my_array[i][j] = i * j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it isn't exactly what i needed, but it helped me figure out what I need to do!